Derivation of two equivalent functions yields different derivation result. Why?
$f(x)=x+\frac{2x^3}{3-2x}-x^2-1 \\
g(x)=\frac{x(3-2x)+2x^3-x^2(3-2x)-3+2x}{3-2x}$
$f'(x)=\frac{-16x^3 + 46x^2 -30x+9 }{(3-2x)^2}\\
g'(x)=\frac{-16x^3 + 50x^2 -34x+9 }{(3-2x)^2}$
Why $f'(x)$ and $g'(x)$ are different?

I think your computation of $g'(x)$ was wrong, see this

It is better if you can show your work on computation, otherwise, we don't know where's the mistake.

You made a computational mistake when finding $g'(x)$. If you ever have a scenario like this where you get two different derivatives for the same function then you know you've made a mistake somewhere.
I would attempt to find $g'(x)$ again and if it does not equal $f'(x)$ once again feel free to post your steps here and someone in the community can help you figure out what went wrong.

$g'$ was computed incorrectly.
